# Get network interfaces on remote machine

Tags: java, network-programming

I know in java we can do `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` to get all available network interfaces on local machine. Can we do similar thing where I can pass host name to get the NICs(with IPs) which are up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot by definition. The IP address is needed to hide the mac address from external world. To retrieve it you definitely need some code running on that machine.

It means that you need some kind of agent. You can either implement it in Java or use platform specific tools. For example you can run `ifconfig` on remote Unix machine or `ipconfig` on remote Windows machine, get and parse its output. Use (for example) ssh, rsh, telnet to run command on remote machine. For windows you can also use WMI.

For all of them you can use SNMP (if it is enabled on remote machine).

Comment: Yeah I would execute powershell command on remote server to fetch network info. Thanks for answer.